# fc-time not showing 'am' or 'pm' fully in events - missing final character

Tags: php, css, fullcalendar

My FullCalendar is having trouble showing the full time, inclusive of the 'am' or 'pm' bit.

It's cutting off the final character, so for example, fc-time is shown as:
"9:45a" instead of "9:45am", or "10:24p" instead of "10.24pm".

What do I need to change so that it shows the final character for fc-time items?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide to accompany your question? That will help greatly to get a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, FullCalendar shows the timed event in this format 9:45a,12a **this is not a problem actually**,

check this demo for [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)
and this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/frra5zjn/1/)

```
events:[
{title:'Event1',start:new Date(2016,05,02),end:new Date(2016,05,04),color:'green'},
{title:'Event12',start:new Date(2016,05,02),end:new Date(2016,05,04),color:'red'},
{title:'Event13',start:new Date(2016,05,02),end:new Date(2016,05,04)}
]
```